# How to apply to a shortcode to work after clicking on a button?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

My question is that how is it possible to apply the shortcode after that when someone clilcked on the button

The **button:**

```
<button class="apply">Apply class</button>
```

The **shortcode:**

```
function color_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
         return '<span class="color">' . $content . '</span>';
}
add_shortcode( 'color', 'color_shortcode' );
```

The **usage**:

```
[color]This is colored[/color]
```

The **work**:

```
<span class="color">This is colored</span>
```

So somebody click on the **Apply class** button and after that where

```
[color]This is colored[/color]
```

was/were defined then it will be like this:

```
<span class="color">This is colored</span>
```

If something is not understandable please write and I will make changes!

I would be happy if its possible to solve with only php and/or css but if not thats not a problem.

Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: It's somewhat unclear, but I think you're asking if you can call the shortcode from javascript, and you can't, it has to run in PHP, on the server, and appending the string `[color]something[/color]` after the page has left the server, does nothing, as the shortcode tags aren't parsed by PHP.

Comment: However, you can send an ajax request on click, use `do_shortcode()` serverside, and just return the result of the shortcode to the ajax call.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that